# Min-cost perfect matching

Tags: algorithm

Given a complete weighted graph with even number of nodes , I would like to compute a perfect matching that minimizes the sum of the weights of the edges (I want it to implement Christofides approx. ) .
I know that Edmond's algorithm will compute a perfect matching in that case (unfortunately not of min cost ).
Is there a simple way to compute a min-cost perfect matching using just Edmond's algorithm and a simple transformation ? If not , how can I do to solve it ?

Thank you for your help .

Comment: Please edit your question as per the SO guidelines or be prepared for a series of downvotes.

Comment: This looks like the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933386/given-a-group-of-people-where-each-pair-has-a-value-how-can-i-find-the-configu.

Comment: Unless this is for a comparison of algorithms, you probably don't want to implement Christofides. If you do, you should probably use [Blossom V](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/papers/BLOSSOM5.html) if you can instead of implementing this yourself. Otherwise, pick up your favorite book on combinatorial optimization and go read about the primal-dual method.