# Given a group of people, where each pair has a value, how can I find the configuration of pairings with the least total value?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, grouping, combinatorics, np

It's very much like the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), except with a complete undirected graph rather than a bipartite graph.

The dumbest, most brute force-iest solution is something like this:

1. Get all possible configurations of pairs...

   `groups = people.combination(2).to_a.combination(people.size/2).to_a`
2. ...rejecting all of the configurations that contain the same person more than once.

   `groups.reject! { |group| group.flatten.uniq.size < people.size }`
3. Then find the configuration with the minimum value.

   `groups.min_by { |group| group.inject(0) { |pair| value_for(pair) }`

Is there a modification of the Branch and Bound solution for the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) that takes into account that, here, the *Job* and *Person* are **both** People?

Could there be another combinatorics problem which more closely resembles what I've presented?

How can I get the best solution without frying my CPU?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but if each *pair* of people has a value, then finding the pair with the lowest value is trivial -- presumably you just need to select on the structure that stores that value?  I'm guessing that you mean something else.

Comment: @AndyJones My apologies for being vague. I'm not looking for the pair with the lowest value, I'm looking to find with superset of pairs has the lowest total value. Say you had ten people, I want to find which of the possible configurations of 5 pairs yields the lowest total.

Comment: Thanks for that -- I'm probably the only person reading this that didn't immediately understand!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in polynomial time with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm#Weighted_matching.